# How we can add a red dotted line under the wrong word in TextDocumentProxy in custom keyboard ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have made a custom keyboard in ios. I am using UITextChecker to check the spelling of entered word in textDocumentProxy on space bar click.

Now my problem is that I have to put a red dotted line under the wrong word on space bar click.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Insert NSAttributedString using custom keyboard extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940768/how-to-insert-nsattributedstring-using-custom-keyboard-extension)

Comment: Is there any other way??

Comment: inthis place try unicode char's, but i m not sure it is work or not

Comment: i am not able to find the underline character there .